# TypeError: The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object. Received type object in cryptoJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, encryption, browserify

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt data on react-native. so I decided to use the crypto node module in my react native project through browserify. Below is the code snippet I used for encryption but it throws the error **TypeError: The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object. Received type object in cryptoJS**. additionally when I use the code in nodeJS, it works fine but in react native it throws that error. what am I doing wrong here? I think the error was initiated from BUffer.from statement which thinks that the variable k is not an array or more like object. but this is my thought I don't know what the real cause is.
Here is the code snippet

```
const algorithm = 'des-ede';
const key = [
      43,
      57,
      97,
      -68,
      -63,
      -61,
      -40,
      9,
      50,
      87,
      -104,
      101,
      63,
      34,
      -78,
      60,
    ];

    var CryptoJS = require('../crypto/crypto');

    var k = new Buffer.from(key);

    let cipher = CryptoJS.createCipheriv(algorithm, k, null);
    cipher.setAutoPadding(true); //default true
    var ciph = cipher.update("Hello World!'", 'utf8', 'base64');
    ciph += cipher.final('base64');

    console.log(ciph);
```

[image]

Comment: In the code `ciphertext` and `cipher` are mixed up and also `ciph` and `ciphertext`. Fix that. Try to replace `null` with `''` in `createCipheriv`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. can you structure as an answer the replace null with '' in createCipheriv, just to accept as an anwser. Thanks

Comment: I doubt that `var k = new Buffer.from(key);` is correct, according to node documentation new Buffer has been replaced by Buffer.from(key), so you can't have both new and from (in node versions later than node 8), so it should be `var k = Buffer.from(key);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was resolved, by just replacing **null** with ' ' in **createCipheriv**, thanks **@Topaco**